# Wake on LAN (WOL) on Mac Pro 3,1 WITHOUT MacOS

Tags: server, mac, wakeonlan

I've been re-purposing my Mac Pro 3,1 (2008) to be a server using docker and Ubuntu Server 18.04.2. I'm trying to get wake on lan to work, as this is a really power-hungry machine and I would rather not let it run all the time.

Everything I can find shows how to enable WOL with macOS, however I have completely removed macOS and now only have Ubuntu server.

Is there some way I can enable WOL using some sort of bios or single user mode or something like that. Or, alternately, is there a way to do this software-only using something like pm-suspend and some other set of tools?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed `ethtool` on the Ubuntu server? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1159293/edit) your question above and copy and paste the output of `sudo ethtool <nic>` where <nic> is the device name of your nic, something like `eth0`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan for details and update your question.

Comment: @jsmith123 Did you solve this? I have the same hardware and requirements.