# Wake on RTC alarm (or on LAN, etc) on Mac hardware

Tags: bios, mac, wakeonlan

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an iMac and it works great, but now I need to set it up to turn on itself automatically at a certain time every day. As far as I can understand, there is no BIOS that can give me such an option, and in the native Mac system it can be accomplished in at least two ways: through System Preferences in the OS, or through the [pmset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pmset) command line utility, also in MacOS.

Is there any known way or trick to do it with Ubuntu installed?

Tried so far:

- search for a linux version of pmset (found the [MacOS source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-211/pmset/), but is it useful?)
- [pm-pmu](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pm-pmu) seems to be related, but does it help?

The problem is also searching for something useful because Linux on Mac hardware is quite uncommon. In principle, the problem is the same as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159293/wake-on-lan-wol-on-mac-pro-3-1-without-macos), regarding Wake On Lan (not solved).

Edit:

Actually, from the comments it turns out wake-on-lan may be used, but it would be only a workaround as, if I understand correctly, it would need a server (and the iMac connected to the network, and placed in the same subnet?) to wake up my iMac. I pointed out the WOL function because it's another example of BIOS setting similar to the one I would need to toggle. The best option would be to make the iMac turn on without any network connection :-)

New edit:
I tried the wake-on-lan method and it doesn't work, despite all the settings seeming to be correct :-(

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (why it's 18.04 with the *year.month* format used) which had 5 years of *standard* supported life..  Run `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm your status, and you'll note EOSS has occurred. Some architectures will continue to get upgrades during May 2023 due to a Canonical decision to extend life (*by one month*), but your system is effectively EOSS now & you should plan your upgraded asap.  EOSS for all 18.04 is 30-May-2023 (ESM starts 31-May-2023)

Comment: thist should have all you need: https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-wake-on-lan-ubuntu/   See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424675/wake-on-lan-broken-after-22-04-update  It will depend on lot on the hardware and on ACPI working with the kernel on your machine.

Comment: @guiverc thanks, I am aware about it, it's indeed a test machine which will be upgraded soon

Comment: @Rinzwind thank you, they can be useful and are actually an acceptable workaround